# Xamarin live player in Ipad - Vizualization Error

Tags: ipad, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 Preview installed yesterday and implemented a simple app which loads responsive site in webview.

Everything works fine in Android mobile using Xamarin live player. However am facing error when am trying to run the application in Ipad xamarin live player.

**Exception** : Vizualization Error
Exception of type 'Fundation.ModelNotImplementedException' was thrown.
(ModelNotImplementedException)

**Environment**: Visual studio 2017 Preview latest.
             Xamarin Forms application using portable class library
             One simple xaml page which loads the webview.

```
MainPage.xaml Code:

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="browser" Source="https://www.example.com" WidthRequest="1000" 
         HeightRequest="1000"></WebView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The player is not working for iOS and PCL at the moment:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95379/xamarin-live-player-ios-foundation-modelimplementationnotfound